# What is the fastest way to transpose a python list clockwise for a given number of indexes

Tags: python, list

I have very big lists of more than 500 elements so I will minimise the example to make the visualisation easier, say I have:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and I was to have a function to which I give a list and a number of places to switch the elements clockwise of the form:

```
def transpose_by_n(list, n):
    pass
```

The result of

```
transpose_by_n(a, 1) will be 
a = [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and the result of

```
transpose_by_n(a, 5) will be 
a = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to rotate a list by n characters.

Comment: yes, cheers didn't realise that there exists a built in for this, but how efficient it is for very big lists?

Comment: @hack-is-art you would probably want to check comments (or add one) on the answers on the duplicate target about how efficient each particular solution is.